# how to get Distinct count based on the condition in power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

I have table name called Data. in this table have a two column Product ,QTY

[image]

Now I have created new measure for DISTINCT Value  for QTY column

**Distict Count Qty = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Data[Qty]))**

Now Table looks like after added above measure

[image]

from above table I want to get count for  three conditions form Distinct Count Qty measure.

if values have < 4  and  if values have => 4 , if value have =12 .

this three count I want from distinct  value measure .